# How to store custom information in SecurityContext of spring-security?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, customization

In my application I'm using LDAP authentication. But i'm also have 2 remote services which requires authentication via method login(username, password). The method returns security token which makes me able to invoke another methods, i.e. I should pass security token to service methods as first argument.
So I'd like to get these security tokens immediately after successful login using LDAP and store them in SecurityContext. I tried to use *authentication-success-handler-ref* of *form-login* element. Using the handler I replace *Authentication* object in the SecurityContext with custom AuthenticationToken that holds not only password but also security tokens. But in this case I have an exception that no authentication provider supports this class of token. 
I know it's also possible to store tokens in the HTTP session but in this case I have to pass session to service object, so I'd like to store the tokens in SecurityContext.

What is the best approach to handle service security token?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I often use the `Authentication.getDetails()` object to store additional info that may not be directly linked to the user per say.  So you can store any object you want in that field (a HashMap for instance) and it shares the `Authentication` object life cycle.

```
HashMap<String, Object> info = new HashMap<String, Object>();
info.put("extraInfo", "info");
auth.setDetails(info);
...
Map<String, Object> i = (Map<String, Object>)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication.getDetails();
```

Answer (score 5):

Your implementation of 'UserDetails' may hold any additional data. This is what gets stored in the SecurityContext which is later accessible after successful login.

You can later access it as (Assumes MyUserDetails implements UserDetails)

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (principal instanceof MyUserDetails) {
  MyUserDetails mud = (MyUserDetails) principal;
  mud.getMyData(); //Extract your additional data here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I can use userDetailsSerivce with LDAP authentication.

Comment: You need not implement the whole UserDetailsService. You can only use your own implementation of UserDetails with LDAP. Here is information on how to do this - http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html#ldap-custom-user-details