# Execute sql statement before normal execution with aop

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, aop, multi-tenant

I'm trying to create a Multitenant application with spring.

I'm trying to have a different schema for each Tenant on a PostgreSql database.

I first created a `TenantAwareDataSource` extending `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDataSource` where basically I manage a Map of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`, configuring setConnectionInitSqls() for each tenant. (The datasource the project had before was `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`)

But then discussing it with a friend, we came up with the idea of changing the schema for every statment executed with an aspect (aop), simply adding a `set search_path to` statement just before normal execution.

This could greatly simplify the problems related to having too many connections to the database (a connection pool for every tenant at any given time).

Has anybody executed additional statements using AOP?
Any pitfalls to overcome?

I'm thinking on put back `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and intercept java.sql.Statements.exe*(..)

I'm not very experienced with Spring persistence. Or SQL statement execution interception for that matter (haha).
Is it ok?

I found [this article](http://beautifulbytes.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/use-spring-aop-and-jmx-to-monitor-and-cancel-jdbc-statements/) but I don't think I need to obtain a reference for each connection.
Am I right?

Also found [this one](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/log-sql-statements-with-parameter-values-filled-in-spring-jdbc/). The author is  using `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations`. Not sure it's the case in my Spring Roo generated project.

Thank you all.